# Gradle could not be resolved for Qt Application build from Windows

Tags: java, android, qt, gradle

I am trying to compile an Android application (С++/Qt) from Windows machine onto a virtual Android.

**Android SDK**: 31 (Android 12)

**NDK**: 21.3.6528147

**Qt**: 5.15.2

**Language**: C++17

Obviously, compilation is for **x86_64** processors.

Compilation breaks at the Android Package generation with following compile output:

```
05:00:15: The process "C:\Users\adzol\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\ndk\21.3.6528147\prebuilt\windows-x86_64\bin\make.exe" exited normally.
05:00:15: Starting: "D:\Qt\5.15.2\android\bin\androiddeployqt.exe" --input C:/Users/adzol/Projects/build-posiflora-pos-Android_Qt_5_15_2_Clang_Multi_Abi_x86_64-Debug/florist/android-florist-deployment-settings.json --output C:/Users/adzol/Projects/build-posiflora-pos-Android_Qt_5_15_2_Clang_Multi_Abi_x86_64-Debug/florist/android-build --android-platform android-31 --jdk "C:/Program Files/java-se-8u42-ri" --gradle
Generating Android Package
  Input file: C:/Users/adzol/Projects/build-posiflora-pos-Android_Qt_5_15_2_Clang_Multi_Abi_x86_64-Debug/florist/android-florist-deployment-settings.json
  Output directory: C:/Users/adzol/Projects/build-posiflora-pos-Android_Qt_5_15_2_Clang_Multi_Abi_x86_64-Debug/florist/android-build/
  Application binary: florist
  Android build platform: android-31
  Install to device: No
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Pos.Controllers
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Pos.Managers
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Pos.Helpers
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Pos.Models
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Pos.Enums
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Pos.DateTimeUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QZXing
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: Clipboard
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Warning: QML import could not be resolved in any of the import paths: QtQuick.Extras.Private.CppUtils
Starting a Gradle Daemon, 1 incompatible and 11 stopped Daemons could not be reused, use --status for details

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android-build'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.
     Required by:
         project :
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.3/gradle-3.6.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.3/gradle-3.6.3.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty
      > Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.6.3.
         > Could not get resource 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.3/gradle-3.6.3.pom'.
            > Could not GET 'https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.3/gradle-3.6.3.pom'.
               > java.lang.RuntimeException: Unexpected error: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException: the trustAnchors parameter must be non-empty

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

I can see that GET request is failing, but first URL (`https://maven.google.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.6.3/gradle-3.6.3.pom`) is viable and I see a .pom file. The question is how I can use this files? However, the second URL returning a 404.

There was several advices, like [this one](https://androiderrors.com/could-not-find-com-android-tools-buildgradle3-0-0-alpha1-in-circle-ci/), suggesting to replace `goolge()` with `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }`. So me `build.gradle` looks like this now:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // Here was google()
        jcenter()
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1'
    }
}

repositories {
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' } // Here was google() too
    jcenter()
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar', '*.aar'])
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion androidCompileSdkVersion.toInteger()

    buildToolsVersion '31.0.0'

    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            java.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'java']
            aidl.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/src', 'src', 'aidl']
            res.srcDirs = [qt5AndroidDir + '/res', 'res']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
            jniLibs.srcDirs = ['libs']
       }
    }

    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.incremental = true
    }

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }

    // Do not compress Qt binary resources file
    aaptOptions {
        noCompress 'rcc'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        resConfig "en"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        targetSdkVersion = 31
    }
}
```

Before replacing `google()` with `maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }` both URLs was unavailable: they returned 404 and 403 error codes accordingly.

And, for good measure, my `gradle.properties` file:

```
org.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx512m
android.bundle.enableUncompressedNativeLibs=false
androidBuildToolsVersion=31.0.0
androidCompileSdkVersion=31
buildDir=build
qt5AndroidDir=D:/Qt/5.15.2/android/src/android/java
qtMinSdkVersion=21
qtTargetSdkVersion=31
```

Honestly, I can't see where to dig now. Any help is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem by:

1. Adding the following lines in `gradle.properties` file.

```
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:/Windows/win.ini
systemProp.javax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=Windows-ROOT
```

2. Selecting right (I don't exactly why, they just works) gradle versions for in `gradle-wrapper.properties`

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.1.1-all.zip
```

And in `build.gradle` in `classpath` I selected gradle 4.0.2 like this:

```
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
}
```

3. In `build.gradle` I added URLs `https://maven.google.com` like that:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.0.2'
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
}
```